# If $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is measurable with $m(E) > 0$, must it contain a closed interval?

Tags: real-analysis

If $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is measurable with $m(E) > 0$, must it contain a closed interval?  I know it has to contain a closed set $F$ with $m(E \setminus F) < \epsilon$ (for any $\epsilon$), but I don't know if it must contain a closed interval.

Comment: Does a singleton count as a closed interval?

Comment: @StevenTaschuk No, and neither does the empty set :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For example, $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ has infinite measure but contains no interval.

Comment: Is there any other example of a set of real numbers with positive finite Labesgue measure but has no intervals? (I read about Smith–Volterra–Cantor set) but are there others sets?

Answer (score 5):

No. Take the irrational numbers, for example.

Comment: I guess that, to be fair, one should give +1 to your answer if and only if one gives +1 to Chris' answer!

Comment: @M Turgeon The two answers have the same time stamp!